# update parent's state fom child component using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to update the number of event from the parent component by using an input form from the child component, but there is something I am not seeing it either doesn't work or shows undefined

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
     numberOfEvents: 32,
  };
.....
 updateNumberOfEvents = (eventNumber) => {
    this.setState({ numberOfEvents: eventNumber });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NumberOfEvents updateNumberOfEvents={this.updateNumberOfEvents} />
}
</div>
```

---

```
class NumberOfEvents extends Component {
  state = {
    numberOfEvents: 32,
  };

  handleInputChanged = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      numberOfEvents: value,
    });
    this.props.updateNumberOfEvents(value);
  };

  render() {
    const numberOfEvents = this.state.numberOfEvents;
    return (
      <div className="numberOfEvents">
        <form>
          <label for="fname"> Number of Events:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="EventsNumber"
            value={numberOfEvents}
            onChange={this.handleInputChanged}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default NumberOfEvents;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
  numberOfEvents: value,
}, () => {
           this.props.updateNumberOfEvents(value);
          }
);
```

The details are [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Answer (score 0):

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859287/11247175) answer does make it work and correctly highlights that `setState` calls are asynchronous, I would suggest removing the local state inside `NumberOfEvents` entirely, as you currently have multiple sources of truth for your form.

Update your `onChange` handler:

```js
handleInputChanged = (event) => {
  this.props.updateNumberOfEvents(event.target.value);
};
```

and pass down the value from the parent:

```js
<NumberOfEvents
  updateNumberOfEvents={this.updateNumberOfEvents}
  numberOfEvents={this.state.numberOfEvents}
/>
```

and use that value inside your child component:

```js
<input
  type="text"
  className="EventsNumber"
  value={this.props.numberOfEvents}
  onChange={this.handleInputChanged}
/>
```

Having one source of truth is less error prone and easier to maintain, as illustrated by your current bug.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with hotpink but i tried your code on codesandbox...it does not show the value undfined. Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-iow19?file=/src/App.js.

Check console